# Is it possible to modify the UI of an MSI created with Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, visual-studio-2019

I have created a setup project with [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects), everything works fine, registry keys, post build event etc .. but is it possible to modify the UI of the installer? for example add a background image, change the font of the characters?

The UI of the current setup look like this

[image: example_setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio installer project is a limited tool that may not provide this sort of customization capabilities. Some properties should be supported, though, through the "Properties" panel of your installer in Visual Studio.

You can also edit the generated installer, there are tools to edit MSI files directly (like [InstEdit](http://www.instedit.com/) or [Orca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe) for example). But this is quite time consuming, and probably more suitable for one-time job and not for a continious development process.

If you want to customize your installer to the maximum extent possible for MSI format, you better pick some other tool for creating MSI, like [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) for example or [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/). Alternatively, if you are okay with .EXE installer and don't necessarily need MSI, you can also pick [NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/) or [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for example (looking at the category of free tools). Something like that could spare you some time you would otherwise spend on learning the internals of the MSI.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the VS installer project. But I can recommend the [Wix Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) .. it is extremely flexible.. sometimes too much), but there you can build you r own screens quite easily.